# How to Consume a WebService using Julia Language

Tags: web-services, elasticsearch, julia

Trying to learn something new this year. started with Julia. Trying to consume a .NET WCF Service which accepts XML and return an XML. Once i receive an XML from the WebsErvice i need to turn it to JSON Object and then Post it to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Did you check -> http://juliawebstack.org/?

Comment: yes, but don't find any example. most examples are to create a web service and not to consume web service.